# Proving $ \mid a - x| > |b - x|$ implies $(a - b)\cdot(x-b)<0$ where $a,b,x\in\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: inequality, vectors, solution-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, triangle-inequality

What am I doing wrong here?

I am trying to show $ \mid a - x| > |b - x|$ using the fact that $(a - b)\cdot(x-b)<0$ for $a,b,x\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

So far, I have done this:

$$(a - b)\cdot(x-b)<0 \implies (a - b)\cdot(b-x)>0$$ $$\implies \text{by Cauchy-Schwarz} \mid a - b \mid \mid b-x \mid > 0$$ $$\implies \mid a - x + x - b \mid \mid b-x \mid > 0$$ $$\implies \text{using triangle inequality} \left(\mid a - x \mid + \mid x - b \mid \right) \mid b-x \mid > 0$$ 
$$\implies \mid a - x \mid > - \mid b-x \mid$$

I shouldn't have the negative sign, but can't see where I am going wrong. Some advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The unnecessary subscript/superscripts make your post hard to follow.   Please consider simply just writing $(a-b)(x-b)<0\implies |a-x|>|b-x|$, or something like this.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool My apologies! I have edited my question to make it easier to follow.

Comment: Your attempt is not incorrect, but it is fruitless.  From $(a-b)\cdot(x-b)<0$, you have $(a-x)\cdot (b-x)>(b-x)\cdot (b-x)$.  Use C-S on $(a-x)\cdot(b-x)$.

Comment: Why do we have $(a-x) \cdot (b-x) > (b-x) \cdot (b-x) $ from $(a-b) \cdot (x - b)<0$?

Comment: What is $(a-x)\cdot (b-x)-(b-x)\cdot(b-x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}(a-x)\cdot(b-x)-(b-x)\cdot (b-x)&=\big((a-x)-(b-x)\big)\cdot(b-x)\\&=(a-b)\cdot(b-x)\\&=-(a-b)\cdot(x-b)>0.\end{align}
Therefore,
$$(a-x)\cdot (b-x)>(b-x)\cdot(b-x)=\|b-x\|^2.$$
By C-S,
$$\|a-x\|\|b-x\|\ge (a-x)\cdot (b-x).$$
Therefore,
$$\|a-x\|\|b-x\|>\|b-x\|^2.$$
Since $\|b-x\|>0$, we can divide both sides of the inequality above by $\|b-x\|$ to get
$$\|a-x\|>\|b-x\|.$$